# SendKeys.SendWait(" "); Throwing StackOverFlowException

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a virtual keyboard in wpf with .Net Framwork and trying to sendkey.sendwait spacebar.

I have searched internet and implementing " " since there is no spacebar special key for sendkeys sendwait method. But its throwing stackoverflowexception after waiting for like 2 minutes.

```
private void Button_Click4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.Button TappedButton = (System.Windows.Controls.Button)sender;
    switch (TappedButton.Tag.ToString())
    {
       case "space":
            SendKeys.SendWait(" ");
            break;

        case "backspace":
            SendKeys.SendWait("{BACKSPACE}");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you send the space key, it clicks the button, which sends the space key, which clicks the button and so on until the stack overflows.

Comment: @Bradley A pretty novel way to create such an exception, if you ask me :-D

Comment: try to read the exception. what does it say?

Comment: @BradleySmith Oh so its like bubbling event? it getting called to parents and so on. oh ok understood. But any advice how to handle this approach?

Comment: @AjayKumar it just says StackOverFlowException nothing else. I am kinda new to c# and got a small project to make a virtual keyboard and messed it up.

Comment: okay you just need to check alternatives as well don't hangup with just one way. try this way here : https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=inputsimulator

Comment: Part of your problem is likely that you're sending the keypress to your own application instead of the active one.

Comment: @PMF yes thats another problem i have to handle or probably dismiss this approach and try another there is no proper tutorial on youtube either which i can follow if you have any link to guide please share.

Comment: @AjayKumar thanks thats a nice article i will try to implement it and update here

Comment: @Liam its a wpf app with .net framework its was creating a ambiguous reference so i mentioned the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was creating stackoverflowexception because it was clicking space again and again using my space reference which i added on SendKeys.SendWait(" "); as mentioned by Bradley Smith on comments.

It was because because the focus of keyboard was on current window so i made the window unfocusable using this code which solved the problem.

```
        protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
            WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
            SetWindowLong(helper.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE,
                GetWindowLong(helper.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE);
        }

        private const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
        private const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
```